# Can a variable contain a switch of function?

Tags: javascript

I've been googling my little heart out, but I either am asking the wrong question, or it's so obscure it doesn't exists. What I would like to know is can you define a variable with a switch inside it. Things to note about my knowledge of programing and on what level I would understand your answer. I'm a graphic/web designer with only a little experience in js.

Something like this...

```
var variable = {
    switch (case) {
      case 'case1':
        return "something";
      case 'case2':
        return "something";
      case 'case3':
        return "something";
    };
  };
```

I know I could just make the switch separate and set the variable per case, but I'm just wondering if this can be done. Also can functions be inside variables? And, how would it be done? Would it be inefficient?

Comment: You're looking for function, not a variable.

Comment: Yes, functions can be set to variables.
See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname?rq=1

Comment: @mc01 What? I don't think the OP is asking to assign a function to a variable, read it carefully, along with existing answers

Comment: @Matt Ball: Oh ya! I didn't think about that. And it is is answered below brilliantly!

Comment: @Juan Mendes, He asked "can functions be inside variables, and how would that be done"? That leads me to assume there's some confusion about how one might declare & store a function in a variable, and what the various syntax options are for doing so. I linked to a question that explains the difference between 2 common approaches.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will sometimes see object literals used in place of `switch` statements. For
example, the following hypothetical syntax:

```
var variable = {
  switch (switchOver) {
    case 'case1':
      return 'something1';
    case 'case2':
      return 'something2';
    case 'case3':
      return 'something2';
  };
};
```

Can be actually written like this:

```
var variable = {
  'case1': 'something1',
  'case2': 'something2',
  'case3': 'something3'
}[switchOver];
```

Which is just a shorthand notation for this:

```
var cases = {
  'case1': 'something1',
  'case2': 'something2',
  'case3': 'something3'
};

var variable = cases[switchOver];
```

Comment: Ah, I was about to post this. +1

Comment: I always recommend using a `undefined` entry in the map to make sure you handle the `default:`

Comment: @JuanMendes: I realized that as soon as I posted that comment lol. My hands were faster than my brain. Interesting solution, @lonut!

Comment: +1 I was about to add this to my answer also... Like my answer, it almost looks like what the OP was trying to do

Comment: This is even better then the answer i was looking for +1

Answer (score 8):

`return` is for returning from a function, not for giving a variable a value. So the answer to the question is No. You can use a self calling function for something that almost looks like what you had.

```
var content =  (function(){
   switch (options.type) {
      case 'image':
        return "<img src="+href+"/>";
      case 'iframe':
        return "<iframe src="+href+"/>";
      case 'swf':
        return 'something else';
   }        
})();
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! Hogan had the same answer. How do i accept both?

Comment: @RyanLutz: You can't choose both. Hohan and Juan will have to fight it out in a battle to the death. That, or you can wait a few minutes and see who has the clearest answer after a barrage of soon-to-come edits.

Comment: I would saw Juan had the clearest answer, as a variable cannot "contain" a function, can derive its value from a self calling function. At least, that's what I think is being said.

Comment: @RyanLutz I think both answers properly answer the question with a (very) slight edge to mine because I do have a function in there and the question does mention function :p I would accept whichever one you end up using

Comment: Hey mine has the function too!  @RyanLutz - Give it Juan -- he beat me by 15 seconds.

Comment: @Hogan Oops, I thought the OP was choosing between mine and ionuț-g-stan's

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple. The easiest solution would be something like this:

```
var content;
switch (options.type) {
  case 'image':
    content = "<img src="+href+"/>"; 
    break;
  case 'iframe':
    content = "<iframe src="+href+"/>"; 
    break;
  case 'swf':
    content = "<object width="+width+" height="+height+" data="+href+"></object>";
}
```

This is clean, efficient, and easy to understand.

If you *really* wanted to use a function, you'd probably want to use an [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (or IIFE):

```
var content = (function() {
    switch (options.type) {
      case 'image':
        return "<img src="+href+"/>";
      case 'iframe':
        return "<iframe src="+href+"/>";
      case 'swf':
        return "<object width="+width+" height="+height+" data="+href+"></object>";
    })();
```

But this is (*slightly*) slower, and harder to understand for the person that comes along after you to maintain your code. Still, it could be useful in some situations, like if you have a bunch of temporary variables that you don't want 'leaking' into the rest of your scope.

I'd recommend you carefully weigh the novelty of this solution against the future maintenance cost.

Comment: "I know I could just make the switch separate and set the variable per case, but I'm just wondering if this can be done." I think OP is aware of this solution already. :/

Comment: Usually the advantage of IIFE is that you can localize variables. I wouldn't try to nitpick the OP's example since they are clearly just trying to figure out if something can be done. I don't think this deserves a downvote though

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm really not trying to nitpick. I'm trying to offer justifications for choosing one method over the other.

Comment: ah didn't see them at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign it an executed function like this:

```
var variable = (function () {
    switch (case) {
      case 'case1':
        return "something";
      case 'case2':
        return "something";
      case 'case3':
        return "something";
    };
  })();
```